# Get parameter in ajax function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

Probably an easy question, but I have been searching for a long time and can not find an answer.

If I have this route (Laravel):

```
    Route::post('clients/{id}/episode/{episodeid}/plans/{planid}/responsibilities',     
    array('as' =>'postajax', 'uses' => 'PlanController@postajax'))
```

The question is: 
How can I retrieve the parameters from the url (id, episode, planid) in the query ajax function?

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    I want to retrieve the parameters here, but how?
    Do I actually need to send them as hidden input?


    }
    });
    });
```

Comment: Are you asking how to get the URL of the current page in JavaScript? (Since that is going to be the same no matter where in the page you are, doing it in a submit event handler is irrelevant).

Comment: Asking how to get the specific parameters as easily as possible.

Example: 'clients/1/episode/34/plans/67/responsibilities'

Then I would be after 
client_id = 1
episode_id = 34
plan_id = 67

Comment: I'm wondering if 'that' form is the one posting to that url. Ok, one thing to consider, POST parameters aren't passed in the URL's query string. POST parameters are sent in the body of the request.

Comment: Then, if the form belongs to the url mentioned in the Laravel route, then yes, you have to "create" some hidden fields to the form, and you can get the values in the Js/JQuery by querying the hidden input values.

Comment: "Asking how to get the specific parameters" … from where? The URL of the current page? The action attribute of the form? Somewhere else?

Comment: @MarkSkayff: Yes, you are right, the form is posting from this url.

Comment: @Bergkamp10 If you are using blade, you can pass the params values to the template, or maybe there's some template helper so you can get the parameters directly in the template using this helper.

Comment: Thanks! Going with hidden inputs for now, while still searching to see if there is an easier way :)

Comment: You have to go with the hidden inputs

Answer (score 0):

I know it's few months pass but

```
$.urlParam = function(name){
var results = new RegExp('[/]' + name + '/([a-z0-9]+)').exec(window.location.href);
if (results===null){
   return null;
}
else{
   return results[1] || 0;
}
};
```

And call it with:

```
$.urlParam('param')
```

Example:

clients/1/episode/34/plans/67

```
$.urlParam('clients') // echoes 1

$.urlParam('episodes') // echoes 34

$.urlParam('plans') // echoes 67
```